# How to set a common date format across the entire Application - Silverlight/Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, datetime, silverlight-toolkit

I am using datetime displayed in a lot of places in my Windows Phone 7 Application. The default date format looks ugly and I formatted it to something like this.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='MMM d, h:mm tt'}"/>
```

The obvious problem with the above code is that I will have to do this copy pasting like everywhere. So, if a date format changes at some place, then I will have to do the same redundantly everywhere. Is there a better way to handle this in Silverlight/C# ?

Even better, is there a way to override Date.ToString() for the entire Application so that I can do the formatting there and I can simply have my code like this (I ask this because I do Ruby and in Ruby this is possible)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
```

If both are not possible, please guide me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) may be?

1. http://forums.silverlight.net/t/12617.aspx
2. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Anuraj mentioned, a ValueConverter might be a very viable solution. Another approach is to create a property for your date string in the object you are trying to bind. I.e.:

```
public class Item
{
    public Date Date { get; set; }
    public string DateString 
    {
        get { return "Today is: " + Date.Month + "/ + Date.Day; }
    }
}
```

Both are viable options, but the ValueConverter makes your code even less redundant. Another option is to make a sort of utility-class, which keeps all your conversion code (i.e. a string representation of a date object - `public string DateToString( Date d )` ).

A third option is to override the Date.ToString() method. The way to do this is simply to derive a class from `Date` (call it `FDate` for example) and simply do this:

```
public class FDate : Date
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // create the string you'd like
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Happy coding!